# What is an Erling brick?

Tags: piece-information, terminology

I have seen people refer to the "Erling brick" or "headlight brick" on LEGO forums. What kind of brick are they talking about?

Comment: What i want to know is why is the stud inset in the brick?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I definitely know them as the headlight brick, and they look like this:

[image: headlight brick geometry]

HoMa's world of bricks has a nice page dedicated to this brick!

http://www.holgermatthes.de/bricks/en/lampenstein.php

LEGO's Pick a Brick lists this as an "Angular Brick 1x1", Design ID 4070 (equivalent to the piece/part id).

Answer (score 22):

[image]

The Erling Brick: named by the LEGO Designer Erling Dideriksen, who invented this element in 1979.

Comment: The model shops refer to this brick as a "washing machine" brick :-)