# What are LDUs and how do they relate to LEGO bricks?

Tags: terminology, size, ldraw

What are LDUs? I see technical people talking about plans and designs in terms of LDUs. I understand it's a measurement unit.

What does it mean and how do LEGO bricks relate to them? Why are they needed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

LDU stands for [LDraw Unit](http://www.lugnet.com/~330/FAQ/Build/dimensions) - the basic unit of measurement in [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org/), the open standard for LEGO CAD programs, and map to the "Fine" grid setting in applications such as MLCad.

Common measurements include:

```
1 brick width/depth = 20 LDU
1 brick height      = 24 LDU
1 plate height      =  8 LDU
1 stud diameter     = 12 LDU
1 stud height       =  4 LDU
```

[image: A 1x1 Brick as 3 Plates in LDUs]
A 1x1 Brick as 3 Plates in LDUs (via [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org/Article218.html#ldu))

The typical LU (LEGO Unit) measurements are coarser at:

```
Brick height = 6
Plate height = 2
Stud pitch   = 5
```

Based on the [physical dimensions of a LEGO brick](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/288/what-are-the-dimensions-of-a-lego-brick), this means that `1LDU == 0.4mm`, based on a stud height (1LU) of 1.6mm.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this all means (along with the answer to the other question) that 1 LDU = 0.4 mm.

Comment: @Random832 consider it done.