# Why does the Erling brick have a ridge below its outward facing stud?

Tags: piece-information, snot

Why does the Erling brick ([#4070](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4070)) have a ridge below its outward facing stud?

[image]

Whereas the more versatile and less common [#87087](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=87087) does not? The #87087 piece also has a better use in SNOT usage, as it can accomadate larger bricks.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The ridge is there to make the base the standard 5LUs wide (see also "[What is an Erling Brick](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-is-an-erling-brick)"), enabling it to accept the standard stud.

I believe the rest of the brick was thinned out so that the combined "depth" of the Erling brick and a 1x1 plate (its common usage as a headlight) was the same height as a standard brick.

From the [HoMa's World of Bricks page on the Headlight Brick](http://www.holgermatthes.de/bricks/en/lampenstein.php):

> If headlight bricks are turned over by 90° and a plate is attached to the stud then this construction is as high as a standard LEGO brick or a layer of three standard LEGO plates.

[image: Stacked bricks - HoMa's World of Bricks]

It also helps to keep the 1x1 plate straight to the bricks edge.

Comment: Good visual explanation.  Amazing little brick.

Comment: Props to HoMa's World of Bricks for the image.

Comment: I've never seen that brick used that way.

Comment: There are a couple more uses as well.  Two Erlings one stud apart can have a horizontal brick connect them.  And you can use 8 to make a cube to which 2x2 plates can be attached (about the size of a Lego die).  Very useful parts!

Comment: @Ambo100 The Cusoo Delorean uses them in [this configuration](http://1drv.ms/1nNAF7t)

Comment: The first use I personally encountered was in 6394: See the top left corner in step 7 of the instructions: [Metro Park & Service Tower](http://peeron.com/scans/6394-1/8/)