# How do I add a light to the Red Cargo Train?

Tags: trains, lighting, set-modification

I want to add [led light](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Light-8870) to the front (and probably back) of the [Red Cargo Train](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Red-Cargo-Train-3677) but the shape of the light is making me wonder what brick I should use to hold the light. I've never seen these lights used anywhere. I'm thinking I'll need something from a Technik set.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you added a link to the Red Cargo Train your are describing.  At least a set number.

Comment: @LarsTech Done. Though, I think the train itself is inconsequential . . . I wonder what brick could hold the light no matter what the application!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These light fit in a regular Technic hole, and thus have the same diameter as a stud.

I would recommend fitting them in the so-called "[Erling](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/39/)" brick; after all, one of its regular (aka "boring") names is "Brick, 1 x 1 with **headlight**":

[image: Brick, 1 x 1 with headlight].

The only problem you'll have is that the light extends quite a bit at the back, but you can easily solve that by using a panel of some sort, for example:

[image: Panel 1 x 2 x 1]

Comment: Are there different versions of the Erling? The ones I have don't have an open back.

Comment: @tooshel Not really, the "Erling" brick is the nickname of the brick illustrated above. However, there is a newer 1x1 brick with 1 stud, where the stud is not recessed, and that had a closed back. That's what Pierre Normandin used for the lights of that train, so you'll have to replace them. You could also use 1x1 Technic bricks if you have some.

Comment: Turns out the Red Cargo train has a grey piece that was just a 1 unit brick with an extra stud on one side so it was way different from being an Erling. With 4 black Erling's and gutting the center of the train for wiring my lighted cargo train is complete! Front and back lighting and it is controlled from the other dial on the remote. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I used a grey 4 stud Technic brick with 4 holes because didn't have two grey 1 stud 1hole Technic bricks. The LED are about 1.33 units high so I had to raise the black platform height to accommodate the width of the LEDs. When I added lights to the Train Engine Operator cabin - I had to create more room inside so the train engine became a bit less sturdy. You can see photos and a video of my solution below.

http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/302348

Comment: Nicely done! I did about the same to the train but I didn't raise the height. I had to gut the middle of the train and removed the minifig cabin area to accomidate the extra wires. I also put lights in the front and back. I noticed you must have raised the height of the conveyor belt too since it has to tip up and down to miss the height of the train.