# Stained glass windows on The Throneroom of Cedrica

Tags: part-identification, building, castle

Can anyone explain how to make the stained glass windows in builds like [The Throneroom of Cedrica](https://www.flickr.com/photos/141735493@N05/33533676713)?

[image: stained glass windows]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I see that this popped up on HNQ, so I wanted to expand on shoover's excellent answer with a build showing one way that this could be put together for folks that may not be as familiar with LEGO elements as the Bricks community.

[image: step 7]

As was already pointed out, the key element here is the 2x2 turntable base without a turntable attached:

[image: turntable bases]

Here's how you might pair those elements with transparent 1x1 and 1x2 elements to build a stained glass window:

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

We leave a couple of 1x2 plates overhanging the back to provide attachment points.

Here it is from the front. Notice that we also add a couple of 1x1 plates on the front side to make the connection points flush with the rest of the window:

[image: step 3]

Now we can build a frame to trim this out and create a nice looking window:

[image: step 4]

[image: step 5]

[image: step 6]

We can then attach our window using the attachment points that we left for ourselves in the back side of the [Erling](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/39/what-is-an-erling-brick) bricks:

[image: step 7]

[image: step 8]

Note that I'm not trying to replicate the exact techniques used by the original designer, but this does show one way to get a similar look. I've added the parts list on [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-45244/jncraton/stained-glass-window/#parts) if you want to see exactly what I used and build this yourself.

Answer (score 12):

From [this picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/henjin_quilones/34343958265/in/photostream/) and [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/henjin_quilones/34343925475/in/photostream/), you can see that the framing of the windows is formed by [Turntable 2 x 2 Plate, Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3680&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) in black.

For the colored areas (the "stained glass"), you have a couple of options:

- You could use different "Trans-X" colored [Plate, Round 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073&idColor=20#T=C&C=20) inserted into the back, but you'll need some trans-clear plates to back them up so the structure holds together.
- You could use different "Trans-X" colored [Plate 1 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3023#T=C&C=108) inserted into the back, in an overlapping/alternating pattern for structural strength.
- You could use a combination, some 1x1 and some 1x2 for strength.

Comment: I don’t think it’s as simple as that. The construction you describe would fall apart, as there is nothing holding the turntables together. There is either a layer of trans-clear plates behind the trans-X 1x1s, or most of the 1x1s are actually 1x2s that are alternatingly placed to either tie the turntable bases to the window frames, or to tie adjacent turntable bases together.

Comment: I started to agree with you, but then I noticed in the above picture in the rightmost panel there is a single blue space with no other blue spaces near it. However, on second or third look, it does appear that many/most of the colored spaces come in pairs. The OP has already accepted the answer; would it be bad form to edit in an alternate explanation using trans-X 1x2s? I think the crux of the question might be about the turntable base, anyway.

Comment: It is fine to update the answer with new details. After all this is how we keep them relevant and update with new information. You can actually have both suggestions in your answer - using 1x1's with extra layer of Trans-Clear plates as well as alternating 1x2 plates.

Comment: @shoover Great update!

Comment: Is there anything saying that any of that picture is legal construction?  Couldn't the windows be the turntable plates glued together and then just have some thin plastic sheet colored with markers for the "glass" behind all of it?  And to answer my own question there is [another photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/henjin_quilones/34343925475/in/photostream/) that clearly shows the tiles stuck behind the plates holding them together.

Comment: It's also possible that each turntable is held via scaffolding or other constructions to a frame behind the wall. if each 2x2 table had 1 2x1 trans plate, that plate could hold it against the columns or a frame behind the columns.

Comment: separating the turntable disk from the turntable, uh, table is already as illegal as it gets, almost as bad as building something from just figure arms or hands.

Comment: @Cee McSharpface these turntables come as two parts in sets. So, unless you have already assembled them together, there is nothing illegal in using just a base.

Comment: really, I was not aware. don't remember to have assembled any of these, and I built many sets - maybe they used to come preassembled in the eighties :). however, this is genius and creative repurposing at its best.

Comment: @Cee as far as I remember yes, they used to. But you know how it is, few seconds for a child to assemble one, a lot of labor costs for the company to assemble all.

Comment: [well, well...](https://imgur.com/gallery/2utdDYI)